# How to correctly use dark mode (nicht) in Android?

Tags: android, darkmode

I am trying to apply dark mode in my app. However, I am not sure how to do it correctly.

Case 1: Only one `themes.xml` and two `colors.xml` (one in `values` and the other one in `values-night`)

Case 2: Two `themes.xml`(one in `values` and the other one in `values-night`) and one `colors.xml`, but with extra dark colors.

Case 3: Two `themes.xml` (one in `values` and the other one in `values-night`) and two `colors.xml` (one in `values` and the other one in `values-night`).

All above cases work in the same way.

Which one is the correct approach?

One more thing, if I use a splash screen (as a Fragment or even an Activity, no matter), at the start when dark mode is activated, firstly the normal colors are always triggered for couple of milliseconds and afterwards it changes to dark/nicht colors.

How to make it run directly trigging the dark/night colors at the start?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

> Which one is the correct approach?

I would suggest 2 , because some times we take color with names like white,pink etc , If white,pink points to different color in night color then it can be confusing .

> How to make it run directly trigging the dark/night colors at the start?

Make sure your app theme extends `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.XXX`

Comment: thanks for your reply. My app theme extends `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`. Actually, the dark mode works. Only that issue I would like to get fixed. Just for perfection.